# Python - Int not iterable -- how to convert a number into a list of that length?

Tags: python, django

I am making an application in Django and Python. I am a student of Web Development.

I have a start date and an end date for a trip model in my database. I am able to get the number of days in a trip by subtracting the two. My question is, based on the number of days in the trip (x) , I would like to create (x) number of html elements (divs).  When I try to do this, I get an error message saying that an Int is not iterable. How do I convert (x) number of days in a trip to a list with (x) items in it?

Thank you

**Code:**

in my models:

```
 class Trip (models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='trips') 
        start_date = models.DateField()
        end_date = models.DateField()
        trail =  models.CharField(max_length=300)
        permit = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
        completed = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
        location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=400)
        lat = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
        lng = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
        created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add =True)

        def __str__ (self):
            return self.trail

        def total_days(self):
            return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days
```

in my template:

```
 <h4>Trip Info</h4>
    <a href = {% url 'final_app:trip_edit' slug=trip.slug %}>Edit Trip</a>

    <p><strong>Trail:</strong> {{ trip.trail }}</p>
    <p><strong>Dates:</strong> {{ trip.start_date }} - {{ trip.end_date}}</p>
    <p><strong> Total days:</strong> {{trip.total_days}}</p>


   {% for total_day in trip.total_days %}
    <h1>test</h1>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `range(number)`

Comment: `[None] * number`, for a list of length `number` filled with `None`

Comment: _How do I convert x number of days in a trip to a list with x items in it?_ What do you want each item of the list to contain?

Comment: How is this code related to your problem?  I don't see where you're trying to iterate over an int anywhere in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let try this

```
def total_days(self):

    return range(self.end_date - self.start_date)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You could use `range`

```
n = 10
n = [*range(n)]
print(n)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 , 8, 9]
```